# Change sequence in an access list for a remote router

Tags: cisco, router

I'm configuring a router for which I have an access list. I know what rules I want to configure, but I can't figure out how to change the sequence for my `ip permit any any` statement. Here is the result of `do sh ip access-list`:

```
Standard IP access list 1
    10 permit any (4539676 matches)
Extended IP access list aSheild
    10 permit ip any any
Extended IP access list aShield
    20 permit ip any any (7101310 matches)
    30 deny tcp any any eq ftp
    40 deny tcp any any eq ftp-data
    50 deny tcp any any eq www
    60 deny tcp any any eq telnet
```

So my question is two fold:
1. Why do I have two `Extended IP access list aShield`?
2. How can I get the permit ip any any to the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. one ACL name is probably misspelled
2. the ACL entries are sorted by the sequence number at the beginning of a line - if you like a `permit ip any any` on the very bottom put it on `9999` or `99999`

Comment: Good point of the misspelling, I'll delete that list. And I know that that's what I need to do, but I can't find any documentation on what that command looks like

Comment: I guess it's in the manual - just `9999 permit ip any any` will do. `no 20` will get rid of the line on top.

Answer (score 1):

Why do I have two Extended IP access list aShield?

A. You don't - check the spelling aSheild & aShield

How can I get the permit ip any any to the bottom?

A.

```
ip access-list extended aShield
no 20
70 permit ip any any
```

You can also get rid of the other access-list with

```
no ip access-list aSheild
```

You can also sort an access list with

```
ip access-list resequence aSheild 10 10
```

The two 10's represent the starting number and the increments

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to just blow out the ACL and add it back in with the correct sequence. You can delete a specific line of an ACL with no 20 but it would be simpler to do this.

>

```
 no ip access list sShield 
 ip access-list extended aShield
>     deny tcp any any eq ftp
>     deny tcp any any eq ftp-data
>     deny tcp any any eq www
>     deny tcp any any eq telnet
>     permit ip any any (7101310 matches)
```